# Create bubble chart with biggest bubble at the center

Tags: r, bubble-chart

I'm trying to create a bubble chart using a set of data as follows:

```
X --> 10
Y --> 20
Z --> 5
Q --> 10
```

I simply need to have the biggest bubble (based on its number) to be at the centre (give or take) and the rest of the bubbles be around it without overlapping.

All of the R examples I have seen require a two dimensional dataset, and since the data I have are only one dimensional, I like to know if it's at all possible to create such graphs in R.

It would be great if someone could suggest me some useful hints or so. By the way for this task I need to use a `SA tools` so something like `d3js` is out of options. However, I am open to using a tool other than R.

I wasn't quite sure if this question should be asked in On [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) or [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com), so if moderators believe it doesn't belong here, I'll remove it.

Comment: Bubble charts typically require _three_ dimensional data: the x- and y-coordinates of the points and the radius of the bubble. With one dimensional data, how would you locate the points or decide the size of the bubbles?

Comment: I strongly agree with @AlexA. A barchart would be much better in this case.

Comment: @AlexA. I basically wanted to assume that the number is the radius of a circle. since I want the biggest bubble to be at the center thus others just rap around it. as i previously said, I'm a total noob in R, so I'm not sure such an assumption is valid

Comment: @nico unfortunately barchart is not relevant to the data I have,

Comment: @nafas, I would recommend to find the proportion of each of the numbers in relation to the total of all the numbers as the sizes of the bubbles. But that would still leave you with only 2 inputs when in fact you need three--x-axis, y-axis, and size of the bubbles. What you can further do is consider your values X, Y, Z and Q as your x-axis values and the integers as y-axis values. This should allow to plot the whole thing using ggplot2.

Comment: @nafas bubble charts have the same problem as pie charts: they misrepresent differences in data, as humans are very bad at estimating differences in area.  This is even worst if you scale the radius instead of the area, as doubling the value means making the circle >4 times bigger. I don't see how a barchart is not relevant: if the data is similar to what you wrote then a barchart is one of the best solutions. If the data is different then please provide the appropriate data.

Comment: See [Plotting non-overlapping circles...](http://grrrraphics.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/plotting-non-overlapping-circles.html)

Comment: @nico I understand what you mean, but based on our research, ppl prefer to see "our data" on bubble chart. two circles with almost same size( i.e. person questioning which one is bigger)  are considered to same. and having the large circles in the middle makes the user to just zoom on it straight away. so I've done my studies abt what chart should be used. just matter of which tool to be used

Comment: @nico http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269  ,   http://www.infocaptor.com/bubble-my-page

Comment: @nafas fair point: statistics vs marketing I guess :D

Comment: @nico if it was for myself I would rather crunch 0s and 1s hehe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do, the main idea being that you sort by the value of the radius, so the first is the biggest, then shift the values around it (odd on one side, even on the other) so that the values are decreasing both ways.

Further explanations in the code.

```
library(plotrix)
library(RColorBrewer)

# Set the random seed, to get reproducible results
set.seed(54321)

# Generate some random values for the radius
num.circles <- 11
rd <- runif(num.circles, 1, 20)

df <- data.frame(labels=paste("Lbl", 1:num.circles), radius=rd)

# Sort by descending radius. The biggest circle is always row 1
df <- df[rev(order(df$radius)),]

# Now we want to put the biggest circle in the middle and the others on either side
# To do so we reorder the data frame taking the even values first reversed, then the odd values.
# This ensure the biggest circle is in the middle

df <- df[c(rev(seq(2, num.circles, 2)), seq(1, num.circles, 2)),]

# Space between the circles. 0.2 * average radius seems OK
space.between <- 0.2 * mean(df$radius)

# Creat an empty plot
plot(0, 0, "n", axes=FALSE, bty="n", xlab="", ylab="", 
     xlim=c(0, sum(df$radius)*2+space.between*num.circles),
     ylim=c(0, 2.5 * max(df$radius)))

# Draw the circle at half the height of the biggest circle (plus some padding)
xx <- 0
mid.y <- max(df$radius) * 1.25

# Some nice degrading tones of blue
colors <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(8,"Blues"))(num.circles/2)

for (i in 1:nrow(df))
  {
  row <- df[i,]
  x <- xx + row$radius + i*space.between
  y <- mid.y

  # Draw the circle
  draw.circle(x, y, row$radius, 
              col=colors[abs(num.circles/2-i)])
  # Add the label
  text(x, y, row$labels, cex=0.6)

  # Update current x position
  xx <- xx + row$radius * 2
  }
```

The result: [image: circles]

[Live version on RFiddle](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=ppnWCEls).

Comment: this is great mate, I was thinking to put the circles in a two dimentional order  e.g. [here](http://www.infocaptor.com/bubble-my-page?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com&size=800).but this seems even nicer